# Find all input with specific keyword

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'd like to find all the inputs that have at the end of their names the keyword `[0]`. I guess I have to use the following method:

```
$("input[name=name]")
```

But how to specify only a part of the name?

Comment: You should read this http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: @Liam this isn't a duplicate of that question. That question doesn't answer how to pull from the **end** of the `name` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be you want this

```
$("input[name$=name]");
```

> Select all elements with a name attribute value ending with `name`.

**[Check Manual](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [Attribute Ends With Selector (`$=`)](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) to match things at the end of the attribute:

```
$("input[name$='name']")
```

> **Description:** Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value ending exactly with a given string. The comparison is case sensitive.

If you want to match `input` elements whose `name` attribute ends in `"[0]"`, you'd use:

```
$("input[name$='[0]']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be you want this
[Check the manual here](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
$( "input[name$='letter']" );
```

or

```
$("input[name^='name[']");
```